# how to autocrop business card images taken from camera using opencv in android

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing, native, edge-detection

I am developing an app that captures a business card using custom android camera and then i need to autocrop the unwanted space in android and then store the image . I am using opencv for this. All examples i am seeing are in python . I need it in android native.

Comment: send the image back to your server...that's one way to make it platform independent.

Comment: Thanks but i need it to be in local for faster results

Answer (score 1):

You can probably try something like this:

1) Get an edge map of the image (perform edge detection)

2) Find contours on the edge map. The outermost contour should correspond to the boundaries of your business card. (under assumption that the business card image is against a solid background) This will help you extract the business card from the image.

3) Once extracted you can store the image separately without the unwanted space.

OpenCV will help you with points 1,2 and 3. Use something like a cannyedge detection for point 1. The `findContours` function will come in handy for point 2. Point 3 is basic image manipulation which I guess you don't need help with.

This might not be the most precise answer out there - but neither is the question is very precise - so, i guess it is alright.

Comment: thanks but i am not as good in those edge detection algorithms. I need some other assistance in that